# Load custom dataset in tensorflow/keras

Tags: python, tensorflow

So in this code author is using MNIST dataset and i wanna use my own dataset which consist of images. I dont know how can give path to my own dataset here?

```
(train_images, _), (test_images, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()



# Load the dataset
(train_images, _), (test_images, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 
                                            config.raw_size,
                                            config.raw_size,
                                            config.channels)
# Add noise for condition input
train_inputs = artefacts.add_gaussian_noise(train_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
train_inputs = data_processing.normalise(train_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_images = data_processing.normalise(train_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
train_labels = train_images.astype('float32')

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_inputs, train_labels))\
            .shuffle(config.buffer_size).batch(config.batch_size)

# Test set
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 
                                        config.raw_size,
                                        config.raw_size,
                                        config.channels)
test_inputs = artefacts.add_gaussian_noise(test_images, stdev=0.2, data_range=(0, 255)).astype('float32')
test_inputs = data_processing.normalise(test_inputs, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_images = data_processing.normalise(test_images, (-1, 1), (0, 255))
test_labels = test_imag

es.astype('float32')
```

Comment: Hey, Saqib! So are you trying to load images from a local (on your computer) folder? What is the format/extension (png, jpeg, etc.)?

Comment: jpeg, and yeah im trying to load images from my own computer directory.

Comment: Hey, Saqib, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data set of images in a folder named `foldername` of type `.jpeg`, would the following solution meet your needs?

```
import glob

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread

foldername = "YOUR FOLDER NAME"

# load in the images as a numpy array of shape (number images x width x height x channels)
image_array = np.array([imread(im) for im in glob.glob(f"{foldername}/*.jpeg")])
```

Comment: No problem, dude. If you don't mind, would you consider posting the answer to your question and accepting it so that future users are able to benefit?

Comment: files_name = os.listdir('dataset/train')   
train_x = []  
for _,i in enumerate(files_name):  
  train_x.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join('dataset/train',i),0))
train_x = np.asarray(train_x).reshape(-1, 512,512, 1)
train_x_28 = []   
for i in range(len(train_x)):  
  train_x_28.append(cv2.resize(train_x[i], (28, 28)))  
train_x_28 = np.asarray(train_x_28).reshape(-1, 28,28, 1)